# TikTok open API video.list Fields request

Tags: php, api, tiktok

Can retrieve videos without any problems but trying to request the 'fields' in endpoint always calls a 404 error. I try to follow the documentation https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-video-list but maybe i'm attatching '&fields' or 'like_count' incorrectly to the url. Not sure how to structure the request.. any help?
Thanks
[error received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msQR2.png)

```html
$tik_token = $tik_tok_access;
$tik_open_tk = $tik_open;


$url = 'https://open-api.tiktok.com/video/list/?open_id='.$tik_open_tk.'&access_token='.$tik_token.'&cursor=0&max_count=1&fields=like_count';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$jo = json_decode($json, true);


var_dump($jo);
```

Comment: The type the documentation lists for `fields` is `set<string>`, meaning you will have to supply an _array_ of string values, not a single string.

Comment: Thank you, but if i declare "$fields = ["embed_html", "embed_link"];" then adjust the url to "$url = 'https://open-api.tiktok.com/video/list/?open_id='.$tik_open_tk.'&access_token='.$tik_token.'&cursor=0&max_count=1&'.$fields.''; " i get an array to string conversion error. A bit new to this.. do you know how i can correctly insert the array into the URL?

Comment: You should prepare the parameters you need to send in form of an array, and then let `http_build_query` take care of creating a proper query string, that also already is properly URL-encoded (which might be necessary for certain values , but which you so far neglected to apply completely.)

Comment: tried 'http_build_query($fields)' but still get same error.

Comment: You need to use this function not for a single parameter, but with an array data structure that contains all of them.

Comment: Okay thank you, I appreciate you putting me in the right direction. I'll see what I can get from. it.

Comment: Something like https://3v4l.org/7Hub1 should probably work.

Comment: Checking the API description some more, I don't think you can get what you want with a GET request to begin with. _"There is a POST method and a GET method, with the POST method providing optional additional video metadata."_ - and the `fields` parameter is to specify which additional video meta data you want, but that would not apply to GET requests then ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php Having a look at this 'Curl-less PHP method' Could be a possible solution?

Comment: resolved. Thanks! https://3v4l.org/NXign

Answer (score 0):

Get method to POST. Called Curl instead.

https://3v4l.org/NXign

```
<?php

$url = 'https://open-api.tiktok.com/video/list/';

$data = '{
    "access_token": "'.$tik_token.'",
    "open_id": "'.$tik_open_tk.'",
    "cursor": 0,
    "max_count": 1,
    "fields": ["embed_html", "embed_link", "share_count"]
}';

$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $additional_headers); 

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

echo  $server_output;
```